# Исконно русские имена

Tags: недопустимая-метка, ономастика

Какие из известных современных имен являются исконно русскими?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самые распространенные исконно русские имена:
-женские: Светлана, Людмила, Руслана, Богдана, Злата, все имена, оканчивающиеся на "-слава" (Мирослава, Ярослава и т.д.);
-мужские: Владимир (произошло от варяжского Вольдемар), Руслан, Борис (сокращенная форма от Борислава), Вадим, все имена, оканчивающиеся на "-слав" (Ярослав, Вячеслав, Святослав и т.д.).
Женские имена Вера, Надежда и Любовь строго нельзя назвать старославянскими, потому что они появились в русском языке с приходом христианства и являются переводом труднопроизносимых имен греческих великомучениц Пистиос (Веры), Эллис (Надежды) и Агапе (Любови).

Answer (score 2):

Всплыл вопрос... Ну придется ответить.

~1. Касательно "русских" женских имен. Забудьте. Их нет. 
Так называемые "славянские": Светлана, Людмила и некоторые другие - позднейшая реконструкция под влиянием славянофильских настроений в обществе XVIII-XIX веков. Распространение получили благодаря поэтам державинской и постдержавинской эпохи (Жуковскому особенно). А Вера, Надежда и Любовь - калька с греческих. Означают они, кстати, основные христианские добродетели: веру в Бога (по другой версии - в бессмертие души), надежду на Спасение и любовь к ближнему (или тоже к Богу).

~2. Имя Владимир - никакое не скандинавское, славянское, но княжеское, т.е. не могло появиться ранее определенного момента, скорее всего Владимир Святославович (Володимѣръ Свѧтославичь) и был его первым носителем. Обратите, кстати, внимание на написание. Там ять, что напрочь исключает этимологию "владеть миром". "Мѣр" - здесь (по версии Фасмера) славянское образование, родственное греческому "великий", т.е. Володимѣр - великий властитель. По другой этимологии "мѣр" может быть и чисто славянским образованием со значением "мера", т.е. значение - "всемерный властитель". Сведения о возможных появлениях подобного имени в родственных языках недостоверны, но могут объясняться и параллельными образованиями.

~3. Руслан - имя ирано-осетинское, "алан" - гордый, мужественный. Аналогчно - Беслан, Сослан и другие. По другой версии - тюркское от "аслан" - лев, но тогда появление "рус" здесь необъяснимо.

~4. Борис обычно связывают с "Бориславом" (борись+слава), но скорее всего это славянизированный вариант имени первого правителя Болгарии, царя Бориса (Богориса). "Богорис" скорее всего имет тюркские корни и, возможно, родственно "богатырь".

*ЗЫ Я сознательно избегаю системной нумерации пунктов списка. Она страшно глючная, поэтому пришлось править даже после модератора.*

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт Владимира не согласен! Явно читаются корни "владеть" и "мир". Может наоборот, скандинавы позаимствовали его из русского?

Comment: Увы, нет. Изначальной формой было все-таки Вольдемар, а потом оно уже "обрусело".

Answer (score -1):

Чего гадать... посмотрите список имён в договоре Олега или Игоря с Византией. Сильно удивитесь. Почти все имена, которые у нас считают 'исконно русскими' в действительности славянские. А Русь и славяне -совсем не одно и тоже.

Comment: Ой, страсти-то какие))) Смотреть договора варягов с греками, чтобы убедиться, что Русь и славяне - это не одно и то же. *"Аффтар пешы исдчо"*. Простите за мой французский.