# Истинно Русские Имена

Tags: имена, др.-русский

Всем доброго времени суток , сразу напишу не судите меня строго за мою орфографию и чтобы то не было , перед мной встал вопрос попытаться узнать выяснить НАСТОЯЩИЕ ИСКОННО РУССКИЕ ИМЕНА , зайдя в интернет первое что по запросу выдаёт это Википедия, даже я не образованный понял что там полная чушь , продолжив поиск я узнал что Елена Екатерина и подобные распространённые имена тоже не являются истинно Русскими , и вот я наткнулся на этот сайт ( форум ) , и в статье [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/204/Исконно-русские-имена](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/204/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) к своему великому удивлению узнал что даже такие имена как Вера Надежда и Любовь тоже производные , участник диалога behemothus который на мой взгляд излагал самую правдоподобную информацию по моему мнению не отвечает , и так у меня огромная просьба ко всем кто будет читать и отвечать на этот вопрос пожалуйста если " не уверенны "что имя действительно Русское - не утверждать об этом , надеюсь я хоть для кого то излажился понятно , заранее всем спасибо и добра !

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, конечно, интересный...
Мало кто задумывался над этим. Все привыкли, что Николай, Сергей, Иван, Петр - это  наши, а значит - русские имена.
А вот ведь это не совсем так, а даже и совсем не так.
Люди, не знакомые с историей или религией, не задумываются или не догадываются, что большинство сегодняшних имен, а даже имен 18 и 19 веков, непривычных нашему уху и давно забытых (типа Дормидонт, Хрисанф, Акакий, Гермоген, Гордей и много других), не являются ни русскими, ни славянскими.
Будучи в Черногории я был знаком с женщиной, имя которой было Весна (ударение на первый слог). Я тогда удивился. Как так! Что за имя! Возможно ли такое! Потом было еще одно имя, мужское, Предраг. Как позднее узнал, это имя тоже древнеславянское.
А в первый раз я столкнулся с этим вопросом при крещении дочери. При рождении мы дали дочери имя Алёна. И когда крестили дочь, священник спросил, - как дочери имя? И когда я сказал, - Алена, был ответ, - в христианстве нет имени Алёна, есть имя Елена. Так и покрестили. Хотя я знал, что у Николая Некрасова была поэма, где фигурировало имя Алёна...
И вот тут то надо вспомнить, что христианство мы приняли от Византии. Причем не просто христианство, а даже и православие. А поскольку с тех пор мы должны были жить по уставу православному, значит и крестить детей, и давать им имена мы должны были в соответствии теми именами, которые были прописаны к применению данной религией (в соответствии со Святцами). А имена славянские, читай - языческие, должны были искоренять. Родился человек, посмотрели Святцы, на какой день приходится рождение, какой святой записан на эту дату - так и назвали. Вот и вся премудрость.
Конечно, с течением времени нравы и порядки менялись, были отклонения. Употреблялись имена греческого происхождения, германского, и разные другие в том числе. Еще, наверное, такие советские имена как Ревпет (Революционный Петроград), Ким (коммунистический интернационал молодёжи), Вилен (В. И. Ленин) и много ещё...

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю рассмотреть имя Всеволод. Это имя трактуется во многих источниках, как праславянское, дошедшее и до наших времен. Сейчас мы это имя знаем как Владимир. Конечно, может это не равнозначные имена, но, по крайней мере, являются синонимами.
Есть такой писатель, Дмитрий Балашов, филолог-русист (!). Его произведения об истории древней Руси, начиная с Великого Новгорода. "Марфа посадница", цикл произведений "Государи Московские", это всё история с тринадцатого века. Человек очень серьёзно занимался историей, изучал русский Север. В его произведениях можно найти еще те имена, которые можно отнести к русским или праславянским.

Comment: У меня сын Владимир , сейчас бог даст родиться дочь хотелось бы ей имя дохристьянское русское , а в будущем с божей помощью надеюсь будет Ратибор и Будимир ! )

Comment: @Арсэн 
Вашим требованиям соответствует имя "Лада".